# props.history.push() doesn't redirect

Tags: reactjs, routes, history

props.history.push("/") doesn't redirect.

I did search for solution for this problem and can't find where is the problem and that drives me crazy.

index.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import App from './App';
//import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

// Create browser history to use in the Redux store
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href');
const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: baseUrl });

// Get the application-wide store instance, prepopulating with state from the server where available.
const initialState = window.initialReduxState;
const store = configureStore(history, initialState);



//Render app on  "root" <div> in index.html 
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <App />         
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));

//registerServiceWorker();
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import Counter from './components/Counter';
import FetchData from './components/FetchData';
import { PrivateRoute } from './components/PrivateRoutes/PrivateRoute';

const App = (props) => {


    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path='/counter' component={Counter} />
            <Route path='/fetchdata/:startDateIndex?' component={FetchData} />
        </Switch>
        );
}

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { withRouter, Redirect, history } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Form, Label, FormGroup, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Home from '../Home';


//Login user
function LoginUser(username, password, callback) {
    console.log("Atemt to login..." + " " + username);

    fetch('api/SampleData/Login', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: username,
            password: password,
        })
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(json =>callback(json))
}

 function Login(props) {

    var logged = false;

    var data = { username: '', password: '', };


    function getUsername(event) {
        data.username = event.target.value;
        console.log(data);
    }

    function getPassword(event) {
        data.password = event.target.value;
        console.log(data);
    }

    function requestCallback(res) {
        if (res[0] === "connected") {


            props.history.push('/');
            console.log(props.history);
        }
    }

    if (logged === true) {

        return (<Redirect to="/" component={Home} />);
    }
     return (
        <div style={{ position: 'absolute', left: '50%', top: '50%', transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)' }}>
             <Form >
                <FormGroup controlId="formBasicEmail">
                    <Label>Email address</Label>
                    <FormControl type="email" placeholder="Enter email" onChange={getUsername} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="formBasicPassword">
                    <Label>Password</Label>
                     <FormControl type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={getPassword} />
                </FormGroup>

                 <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => LoginUser(data.username, data.password, requestCallback)} style={{ margin: '0 auto', display: 'block', width: '100px' }}>
                    Login
                 </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>

    );
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

As you can see Login component is wrapped with withRouter(Login).  console.log(props)  in Login.js file shows that history is passed to props.

Comment: Would you mind providing the code of your `PrivateRoute` component?

Comment: what is the error thrown by react ?

Comment: Hello no errors

Comment: @Rallen   import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    const userLogged = false;
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => userLogged ? (<Component {...props} />) : (<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />)}
        />
        )


}

Comment: @QuickBytes The code is better placed in your post instead of the comments.

Comment: Sorry im new here i dont know how to format code in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your PrivateRoute you have a constant variable called `userLogged` which is initiated with the value `false`. If the variable is `true`, the defined component is rendered. If it is `false`, you redirect ot `/login`.

The value of `userLogged` is always `false`, so you always redirect to `/login`. I recommend you handle your logged-in state either in your parent component `App` or through the usage of a store from `redux`.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem... But one think was confusing me. when i did use <Redirect />  it worked.  Page was redirected, but because of false value i always get redirected back to /Login.  And i expected same result with props.history.push('/').

Answer (score 0):

Use 'history' npm package

1)App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard.js ";
import Login from "./components/login.js";
import Profile from "./components/profile.js";
import PrivateRoute from "./privateRoute.js";

export const history = createBrowserHistory(); 
//refer 'history' for wanted component like profile.js

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/"
            component={Dashboard}
            exact
          />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact />
          <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

a)Once you login store some data in local Storage with key "user".

b)Based on this "user" object in localStorage routing will happen in prBivateRoute.js

c)If you want to log out clear localStorage it will navigate into loginPage

2)privateRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (localStorage.getItem("user")!= "") {      
          return <Component />;   
        }else {
           return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />;     
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

3)profile.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { history } from "./App.js";

class Profile extends Component {
  goBack = () => {
    history.push("/");
  };

  render() {
    <button onClick={() => this.goBack()}> back to dashboard </button>;
  }
}

export default Profile;
```